# How do I remove a label from a gmail message?

Tags: gmail-labels

I accidentally gave a sent message three labels but only want it to have one.  I cannot figure out how to remove the incorrect labels from the message.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1. click on the message to open it.
2. Each label will have a little x next to the name. Click the x's for the ones you want to remove.

Or

1. put a check box next to the message.
2. Select the label button.
3. A drop down will appear, deselect any of the labels you no longer want.